# Function to return OnClickListener object in Android

Tags: android, onclick, onfocus, onclicklistener, oncheckedchanged

So I made a little research trying to find a function to return an OnClickListener Object for a RadioGroup and one good lead was a question asked by "[pedromateo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6610143/1328476)" and a hopeful answer was given by "[Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069957/1328476)" BUT I couldn't even find the function "getOnClickListener()" or else I wouldn't be asking for help.

So please somebody direct me in the right direction.

-Edit-

Some might want to know why would I want to do that so as an answer:

```
public class CompositeOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    List<View.OnClickListener> listeners;
    public CompositeOnClickListener() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<View.OnClickListener>();
    }
    public void addOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (View.OnClickListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    }
}
```

[Copied from [DeeV's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7587569/1328476) answer here.]

So I will use that class to add multiple listeners to the same object and I want the user to add his `OnClickListener` to the object and I will get it using the non-other-than the Non-Existing "`getOnClickListener`" function and add it to the `CompositeOnClickListener`.

Any Ideas will be appreciated.

-Edit(2)-

Why is there a `getOnFocusChangedListener` but not a `getOnCheckedChanged` or `getOnClick`?

That really confuses me and bums me out. =(

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method in your class that extends `View`, `View` does not have such method.

Comment: It's not my Class it's the Android RadioGroup class and I don't want to make it necessary to use a custom RadioGroup class.
And it already extends the View Class but even a View object doesn't have the fore-mentioned function.