# getOnClickListener() in Android views

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I need a getOnClickListener() for Views in Android. This way I can assign a temporary OnClickListener to my Views. 
I want to use it like this:

```
private View.OnClickListener oldListener;

public void assignTempListener(View view) {
    oldListener = view.getOnClickListener(); // doesn't exist

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // some code

            v.setOnClickListener(oldListener);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that this function doen't exist. I also can't inherit from View to create this method, because all kind of Views can be passed to assignTempListener. Is there another way to use this?

Edit: made a small mistake in my code.

Comment: I want to assign a temporary OnClickListener to an already exiting View. I don't have control where the orginal OnClickListener is assigned. So I can't store it there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this with...**REFLECTION**. *drum roll*

This route is fraught with peril.

I don't recommend it, as the internal structure of the class can change at any time, but here's how you can do it currently up to Android 4.2.2 if it's truly unavoidable:

```
/**
 * Returns the current View.OnClickListener for the given View
 * @param view the View whose click listener to retrieve
 * @return the View.OnClickListener attached to the view; null if it could not be retrieved
 */
public View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener(View view) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        return getOnClickListenerV14(view);
    } else {
        return getOnClickListenerV(view);
    }
}

//Used for APIs lower than ICS (API 14)
private View.OnClickListener getOnClickListenerV(View view) {
    View.OnClickListener retrievedListener = null;
    String viewStr = "android.view.View";
    Field field;

    try {
        field = Class.forName(viewStr).getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");
        retrievedListener = (View.OnClickListener) field.get(view);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        Log.e("Reflection", "No Such Field.");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Log.e("Reflection", "Illegal Access.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e("Reflection", "Class Not Found.");
    }

    return retrievedListener;
}

//Used for new ListenerInfo class structure used beginning with API 14 (ICS)
private View.OnClickListener getOnClickListenerV14(View view) {
    View.OnClickListener retrievedListener = null;
    String viewStr = "android.view.View";
    String lInfoStr = "android.view.View$ListenerInfo";

    try {
        Field listenerField = Class.forName(viewStr).getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
        Object listenerInfo = null;

        if (listenerField != null) {
            listenerField.setAccessible(true);
            listenerInfo = listenerField.get(view);
        }

        Field clickListenerField = Class.forName(lInfoStr).getDeclaredField("mOnClickListener");

        if (clickListenerField != null && listenerInfo != null) {
            retrievedListener = (View.OnClickListener) clickListenerField.get(listenerInfo);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        Log.e("Reflection", "No Such Field.");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Log.e("Reflection", "Illegal Access.");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e("Reflection", "Class Not Found.");
    }

    return retrievedListener;
}
```

Comment: I vote Android just add `getOnClickListeners()`. I have jail-broke private members before, but I won't if I can write automated tests that merely call the listener I passed into `setOnClickListener()`... leaving a tiny gap in testing

Comment: Not only that the internal structure might change but reflection is slow and strongly discouraged in Android.

Answer (score 8):

you can override the class and declare a onClicklistener for your view and write setter and getter for onClickListener field:

```
public class SAutoBgButton extends ImageButton {

  public View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

  @Override
  public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    super.setOnClickListener(l);
    mOnClickListener = l;
  }
  public OnClickListener getmOnClickListener() {
    return mOnClickListener;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer can be sooo easy

```
OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        clickableView.performClick();
    }
}
```

Full functionality of onclicklistener except one thing - you can not pass any view as argument into it, `clickableView` will be the handler, but in most cases it is enought

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 oldListener = new view.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // some code

          v.setOnClickListener(oldListener);
        }
    });
```

instead of

```
oldListener = view.getOnClickListener(); // doesn't exist
```

**getOnClickListener** is not any method for [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) or for [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) in Current API's see docs for more details

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: I have made a mistake: 
`oldListener = view.setOnClickListener(); // doesn't exist`
had to be
`oldListener = view.getOnClickListener(); // doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1):

you may need `View.hasOnClickListeners()` that returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Niet!

The oldListener in the answers given is in each case being redefined and it's old state or definition is lost regardless of it's name pretending otherwise.

Following this technique:
[Get current onClickListener of an Android View object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610143/get-current-onclicklistener-of-an-android-view-object)
the 'old' listener would be set in the abstract class's onClick method
and any temporary listener would use setOnClickListener along with a call to super in order to (re)set the old listener when or as appropriate

The temp listener setting code need  not know what the 'old' listener is however
there still needs to be some form of coordination in order for the author of that or those listeners to make them abstract and use the onClick method to set the on click listener, in short, to follow a protocol.

Exceptionally you might want to bypass the protected or private qualifier of the onclicklistener View member: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java#View.0mOnClickListener
and then do a little http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=321191
which will get you the listener.

You might even want to write your own getOnClickListener, or any getter for that matter, that uses the instrospection approach, if of course it actually works :)

:)