# How to Hook into Existing Event Listeners

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a Java SDK which gets installed by the original developer in his existing Android app. Now I need to set some event listeners e.g.:

```
public void registerTouchListener(ScrollView scrollview) {
  scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      Log.d("SDK", event.toString());
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

The issue is that the passed in scrollview might already have a registered listener, so my question is how I can hook into the existing listener or register a second listener?

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is "you don't do either of those", as there are no getters for the listener setters.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, still I need to achieve the gist of my idea somehow... Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide your own API for them to supply the `ScrollView` listener, where you implement the composite pattern yourself, to forward the events to both listeners. Then, document the heck out of this, so developers know that you're taking ownership of the touch listener, and they need to call your API rather than call `setOnTouchListener()` themselves.

Comment: Yeah good idea; I was also thinking about writing a polling class that checks properties via reflection, eg check scrollY or sth - what's your thought on that?

Comment: I have no idea if that would work well, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too hacky, but could you somehow "Steal" the touch event before it gets to the Scrollview by checking the coordinates of where the touch is going to land and if it's in your list of registered Scrollview.  Then act as if you haven't handled the touch event -- that way you could act on that Scrollview prior to it being passed on the touch event?

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I do now by getting the original Listener, then registering my new one and calling the original listener from within, e.g. as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609576/how-to-register-multiple-listeners-in-android?noredirect=1#comment56964298_34609576 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186960/getonclicklistener-in-android-views/14993764#14993764

Answer (score 1):

Rather than providing the API like this, could you rather provide an API that had a function which would call onTouch directly at the end (or beginning) of their event?  Not quite as friendly because it won't live in the initialization section, but it will be much clearer and less buggy.