# How to Register Multiple Listeners in Android?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

In iOS I can register multiple target+action event handlers for e.g. a button like this:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 300, 40)];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(handler1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(handler2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)handler1 {
    NSLog(@"Click handler 1"); // FIRES!
}

- (void)handler2 {
    NSLog(@"Click handler 2"); // FIRES!
}

@end
```

I want to achieve something similar in Java/Android, unfortunately this won't work so far as the first listener gets replaced by the second:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Click Me!");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Test", "Click handler 1"); // DOES NOT FIRE!
      }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Test", "Click handler 2"); // FIRES!
      }
    });

  }
}
```

I appreciate any help & suggestions to achieve the same in Java/Android!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: I am working on a Android SDK that needs to add behavior to existing UI elements during runtime. E.g. to send the click event to our server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not handled the same way in Android and it is just simpler to create two methods as such:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        method1();
        method2();
      }
    });

   private void method1(){
     Log.d("Test", "Click handler 1");
   }

   private void method2(){
     Log.d("Test", "Click handler 2");
   }
```

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) for `View.OnClickListener` state:

> Register a callback to be invoked when this view is context clicked. If the view is not context clickable, it becomes context clickable

Multiple callbacks are not implemented by default, but you could implement it yourself.

Comment: Good idea, let's say the Button already has a OnClickListener, do you know of any way to get that listener during runtime?

Comment: @BenMarten There is no equivalent `getOnClickListener` so with View classes it is not possible

Comment: I found this answer, seems with reflection it's possible. I will try this route. Thanks for your answer & help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14993764/2302437

Answer (score 3):

Read about RxJava it is the future :)
http://reactivex.io/

```
ViewObservable.clicks((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.comment_btn))
            .compose(lifecycleMainObservable().<OnClickEvent>bindLifecycle())
            .subscribe(new Action1<OnClickEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                    Log.d("Button click", "Button 1 click");
                }
            });

ViewObservable.clicks((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.comment_btn))
            .compose(lifecycleMainObservable().<OnClickEvent>bindLifecycle())
            .subscribe(new Action1<OnClickEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                    Log.d("Button click", "Button 2 click");
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `compose(lifecycleMainObservable().<OnClickEvent>bindLifecycle())`

Comment: You can read something about it here https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle. It also prevents from NPE on views when observable emits value after view is destroyed and you are trying to set some value inside subscribe action